# Unable to store referencing key in the table using hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, maven

I am trying to save Customer details (Id, First Name and Last Name) in customer table and Orders by customers (Id and Order Number) in orders table.

When using hibernate to store those details in MySQL database it should store referencing key (customer id) in orders table as Customer and order has one to many relationship.

But when I fetch the data in the database, the customer id column in orders table has NULL values. Why am I not able to store the customer ids in that column?

**Customer.java**

```
@Entity
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    
    private Name name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer")
    private List<Order> orders;
    
    public Customer() {
    }
    

    public Customer(Integer id, Name name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Customer(Integer id, Name name, List<Order> orders) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.orders = orders;
    }


    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    
    public Name getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(Name name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Order> getOrders() {
        return orders;
    }
    
    
    public void setOrders(List<Order> orders) {
        this.orders = orders;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Customer [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", orders=" + orders + "]";
    }
}
```

**Name.java**

```
@Embeddable
public class Name {
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    public Name() {
    }

    public Name(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Name [firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + "]";
    }

}
```

**Order.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Orders")
public class Order {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "Id")
    private Integer id;
    
    @Column(name = "OrderNumber")
    private String orderNumber;
    
    @ManyToOne
    private Customer customer;

    public Order() {
        
    }
    
    public Order(Integer id, String orderNumber) {
        this.id = id;
        this.orderNumber = orderNumber;
    }

    public Order(Integer id, String orderNumber, Customer customer) {
        this.id = id;
        this.orderNumber = orderNumber;
        this.customer = customer;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getOrderNumber() {
        return orderNumber;
    }

    public void setOrderNumber(String orderNumber) {
        this.orderNumber = orderNumber;
    }

    public Customer getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }

    public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Order [id=" + id + ", orderNumber=" + orderNumber + ", customer=" + customer + "]";
    }
}
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ecomtest</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">username</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**App.java**

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();
        orders.add(new Order(101, "A124B"));
        orders.add(new Order(102, "A124C"));
        Customer c1 = new Customer(1, new Name("Hardik", "Jain"), orders);
        
        Configuration con = new Configuration().configure().addAnnotatedClass(Customer.class).addAnnotatedClass(Order.class);
        
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = con.buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        
        Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(c1);
        for(Order order: orders) {
            session.save(order);
        }
        t.commit();
    }

}
```

**customer Table**

```
id first_name  last_name 
1   Hardik      Jain
```

**orders Table**

```
Id  OrderNumber customer_id
101   A124B       NULL  
102   A124C       NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Following changes resolved the issue:

- Set the customer for every Order object
- Set orders for Customer object (c1)

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();
        Customer c1 = new Customer(1, new Name("Hardik", "Jain"));
        orders.add(new Order(101, "A124B", c1)); // set customer
        orders.add(new Order(102, "A124C", c1)); // set customer
        
        c1.setOrders(orders) // separately setting orders

        Configuration con = new Configuration().configure()
                 .addAnnotatedClass(Customer.class)
                 .addAnnotatedClass(Order.class);
        
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = con.buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        
        Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(c1);
        for(Order order: orders) {
            session.save(order);
        }
        t.commit();
    }

}
```